# Customize web site for Anonymous users and remember settings and information

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a E-Shop Site and I need some customization for my users like following :

1. Store favorite products in their own basket.
2. Customize products list in order to what are their favorite.
3. It must remember their basket next time they want to visit our site.

my question is how I can store information for my customers who are new to my web site also most of customers don't like to have username and password then login first they like to buy during a week and at the end of week pay for them then we can send some products to their locations.

I have already written my application using asp.net with framework 4.0.
So what is the best solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net profile is an easiest way to implement it. [Implementing a Profile Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0580x1f5.aspx) and [Profile Example: how to use profile in asp.net](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/profile-example-how-to-use-profile-in.html)  and [ASP.NET Profile Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)

The profile mapped automatically as you mentioned; anonymous users can add items to basket and their information persist and will be available when they next visit the site and when they logged in or get registered their basket information will be migrated to their account through code easily.

Comment: but it uses cookie, Are you sure ?

Comment: @kamiar3001, yes it uses cookies to identify user.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need some way to identify your users. You could try using OpenID or Facebook authentication, they won't need to have a username/password pair that way. However, without something like that, your best bet is probably cookies - I wouldn't go with that idea.

Comment: Please help me how I can use OpenID ? it is good idea I think

Comment: I don't develop in asp.net, but I'm sure you can find tons of tutorial, maybe even libraries that do what you want. Maybe http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133921/what-openid-solution-is-really-used-by-stackoverflow/5133923#5133923

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only one thing! [cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx). But don't you think it will be a bad idea to use your website in a public computer?