# OpenId update profile information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

What is the recommended solution for keeping track of the current user in a site using OpenId? Say I have a Users table with an id and a claimed identifier and then my site specific info and the user wants to update their site specific info. What is the best way to track the current user given that I am not using the built in membership? Should I send a request to openid to get the ClaimedIdentifier each time a user attempts to update their profile? Or perhaps just enforce a UserName be unique and get the user's info based off of User.Identity.Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it with a cookie :)... you might find my answer useful: [What OpenID solution is really used by Stack Overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133921/what-openid-solution-is-really-used-by-stackoverflow/5133923#5133923)

I've also made a simple blog post about it: http://codesprout.blogspot.com/2011/03/using-dotnetopenauth-to-create-simple.html

```
public class User
{
    [DisplayName("User ID")]
    public int UserID{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Open ID")]
    public string OpenID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("User Name")]
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
}
```

In my example I signed in with the OpenID and I stored it in the cookie, but you can store other information in the cookie, such as the user name:

```
public class FormsAuthenticationService : IFormsAuthenticationService
{
    public void SignIn(string userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(serName)) throw new ArgumentException("The user name cannot be null or empty.", "UserName");

        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
    }

    public void SignOut()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    }
}
```

**Update 2.0:**
How about something like this (this is the View):

```
<%
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
    {
        string name = Request.Cookies[Page.User.Identity.Name] == null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[Page.User.Identity.Name].Value;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            name = Page.User.Identity.Name;
        }
%>

        [<%: Html.ActionLink(name, "Profile", "User")%> |
         <%: Html.ActionLink("Log out", "LogOut", "User") %> |
<%
    }
    else 
    {
%> 
        [ <%: Html.ActionLink("Log in", "LogIn", "User") %> |
<%
    }

%>
```

And the Controller, presumably you're taken to a `Profile` page after you log in (or you could set the `Response.Cookies` in the `LogIn` method) and when you're loading up the model you set the display name in the cookie:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Profile(User model)
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            userRepository.Refresh();
            model = userRepository.FetchByOpenID(User.Identity.Name);

            // If the user wasn't located in the database
            // then add the user to our database of users
            if (model == null)
            {
                model = RegisterNewUser(User.Identity.Name);
            }

            Response.Cookies[model.OpenID].Value = model.DisplayName;
            Response.Cookies[model.OpenID].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5);

            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("LogIn");
        }
    }
```

You can see it all in action on a little project I have: [mydevarmy](http://www.mydevarmy.com). I'm going to post a user profile soon and you will be able to change the display name (which is automatically generated for now).

Comment: Agreed.  Despite not using ASP.NET Membership, you can and should still use FormsAuthentication sign-in cookie to remember which user logged in.

Comment: @Andrew, from THE MAN himself! I feel like I'm doing something right :)... anyway, thanks for giving us DotNetOpenAuth: it makes my life MUCH easier and in return I'm implementing it everywhere I go!

Comment: @Lirik, cool, this is very similar to what I have so I think I am on the right track. I am a bit stuck though on how you get the current user when trying to update his profile information. The name you use to set the cookie is a friendly name so couldn't there be more than one user with that friendly name? Or do you use the claimed id and if so, do you have to use Session state to get to the friendly name?

Comment: @Joe, you can set the friendly name to be anything you want... even if users share the same friendly name, they're not sharing the same cookie so as far as I can see it shouldn't be a problem. If your server depends on the friendly name to be unique, then you can enforce a unique friendly name (i.e. use the `UserID` instead of the `UserName`). If you need to find the `UserName`, then you look it up from your database by the `UserID`.

Comment: @Lirik, I see. In a perfect world I would like to be able to quickly display the friendly name simply with User.Identity.Name but then be able to get the current user's profile information using the claimed id or a user id I suppose. I was leaning toward putting both in the cookie since this seemed to be the only way to get this behavior.

Comment: @Joe sorry it took me a while to get back at you... gotta get some work done :)... but I've updated my answer with a specific example which might help you.

Comment: I would urge use of Claimed Identifier as the username because ASP.NET security mechanisms all assume the username is the unique value that identifies the user.  If it's just the friendly name, then that allows for collisions and thus user privacy attacks. One trick you can do is mint your own FormsAuth cookie so that it contains a special field that contains the friendly name (while still using the username field for the claimed id). See http://bit.ly/filalh for an example of injecting an extra string in the cookie, and http://bit.ly/eP8V87 for how to read it.

Comment: @Andrew Arnott: would a database generated unique UserID be sufficient also? I think I had the same issue as the OP: I was authenticated with the claimed identifier, but I had no persistent way of displaying user-specific information (such as the Display Name). In my application I use the claimed identifier with FormsAuthentication and I pass the display name in the cookie... this way I always show the correct display name and I'm always identified with the unique claimed identifier.