# OpenID and Google.GData.AccessControl.dll in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, openid, gdata-api

I am designing a web site to use OpenId and Google is one of the main providers I have selected.  What I would like to do is use Google's Calendar & Contacts (possibly docs) as a backing store for each individual user.  In other words, if the user on my site wants to have access to a Contacts List, Calendar, etc they must register their Google account.  Then they can add/edit/delete to their heart's content as it is their info.  (And yes, I have a specific idea in mind for where I am going, just need to figure out how to tie OpenID to GData.)

Has anyone written a tie in between OpenID/OAuth and using the Google APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging in to this problem I have 2 ways of solving this.

1. Use OpenID and on the user's profile, have them enter their google credentials (works but not a great solution)
2. Use OAuth.  This requires registering your domain with google and getting a key to use with OAuth.  Once you set that up it is easy to access a end user's data stores on google.

Look at google's [OAuth 1.0 for Web Applications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth.html).

Also look at [OAuth-OpenID: You’re Barking Up the Wrong Tree if you Think They’re the Same Thing](http://softwareas.com/oauth-openid-youre-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-if-you-think-theyre-the-same-thing) for a good overview of OpenID vs OAuth.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [DotNetOpenAuth](http://otnetopenauth.net)? It will allow you to connect to any open authentication provider that supports OpenID and Google is one of the [providers listed on the OpenID page](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/).

> Has anyone written a tie in between
>   OpenID/OAuth and using the Google
>   APIs?

I'm not sure what you mean by that... if you're asking if there is a library that allows you to user your google account as an OpenID, then yes: DotNetOpenAuth. There are some catches tho, see [Andrew Arnott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725271/how-to-use-dotnetopenauth-to-login-to-websites/5731260#5731260) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725271/how-to-use-dotnetopenauth-to-login-to-websites/5725788#5725788).

Comment: yes I have and in fact that is what I am using.  Not fully implemented yet as I also have Membership in my app.  What I am trying to figure out is once a person is logged in, how do I connect to their GData.

Comment: @Keith Barrows: unfortunately I have never done that... I can't help you beyond what I've already provided :(, sorry!

Comment: No worries.  I have to get my GData connection working first anyways.  While in dev I am just forcing my google account into the test and so far it keeps coming back 401!  <grrrr/>

Comment: As an update, I do have it now where I can get to GData via someone else's account credentials.  Still working out the fine details with a mixed login environment (OpenID/OAuth/Forms Auth).  Will post more as I close in on a solution.